# android sdk manager gives different results when run from eclipse and command line

Tags: android, eclipse

When I run the SDK manager from the command line I see this in the log:

```
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
...
  Found Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 12
  Found Android SDK Tools, revision 20
...
```

When I run the SDK manager from within eclipse I see this instead:

```
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
...
  Found Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 14
  Found Android SDK Tools, revision 20.0.3
...
```

I only have one copy of the Android SDK installed on my system.  Is there some argument eclipse is passing to the SDK manager when it launches it that causes it to recognize "minor versions"?  Because it looks like the two methods are parsing the same XML.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it had something to do with the cache used by the SDK manager.  Apparently when I ran it from the command line it was picking up stale data.  Clearing the cache made it so both versions see the same packages.